# Is it possible to replace only one character in a string if that character appears twice consecutively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

So I made a method to make the first letter of all the words in any string Uppercase.

```
String.prototype.toMyCase = function () {
    let strArray = Array.from(this.split(" "));
    for(let i=0; i<strArray.length; i++){
        strArray[i] = strArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + strArray[i].substr(1);
    }
    let newStr = strArray.toString();
    let finalStr = newStr.replace(/,/g, " ");
    return finalStr;
};
```

The problem with this is when I pass a string that has real commas(,) it replace that comma(,) too in the finalStr step. For e.g 
`console.log("How can mirrors be real, if our eyes aren't real".toMyCase();` gives me

*How Can Mirrors Be Real  If Our Eyes Aren't Real* (there are two spaces after Real).

Comment: `strArray.join(" ")`???

Comment: Also `this.split(" ")` is *already* an array, so running it through `Array.from()` is totally redundant.

Comment: Not to mention the whole thing can be replaced with a simple regex replace: `String.prototype.toMyCase = function() {return this.replace(/\b\w/g,c=>c.toUpperCase());}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strArray.join(' ')`;

```js
String.prototype.toMyCase = function () {
    let strArray = Array.from(this.split(" "));
    for(let i=0; i<strArray.length; i++){
        strArray[i] = strArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + strArray[i].substr(1);
    }
    return strArray.join(' ');
};
console.log("How can mirrors be real, if our eyes aren't real".toMyCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about with this single line soln after string `split()`, **uppercase** first character and join the rest using `.map()` with the first?,

```js
let str = "How can mirrors be real, if our eyes aren't real";
let captialized_words = str => str.split(' ').map(w => w.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + w.substring(1)).join(' ')
console.log(captialized_words(str))
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

`let finalStr = newStr.replace(/,/g, " ");`

Do

`let finalStr = newStr.replace(/,/g, "");`

Comment: How does this help preserve the `,` in the original string?

Comment: If he's doing `.replace(/,/g, " ");`in his code, I assume he does not want the commas. Else, why would he do that?

Comment: Because OP has no clue what they're doing, that's why they're here. But they did at least quite clearly state that they want commas from the original string to be preserved.

Comment: `Because OP has no clue what they're doing` I guess you're right